# Table column name design

Tags: database, database-design

Let's say I have the following tables: `Customer` and `Staff`.

```
Customer (CusID, CusName, CusAddres, CusGender)
Staff (StaID, StaName, StaAddress, StaGender)
```

vs

```
Customer(ID, Name, Address, Gender)
Staff(ID, Name, Address, Gender)
```

Which design is preferred and why?

Comment: I would personally pick #2 - it has a lot less redundancy and unnecessary repetitions. If you use `Customer.ID` it's already clear enough that you're dealing with a customer - no need to repeat that in the `CusID` column name ...

Comment: I would strongly advise **not** to use MixedCase. SQL per se is case insensitive by default, but DBMS implementations can change this. Migrating to another platform will be less painful if you stick to lowercase (and maybe underscore) Also: avoid reserved words,  keywords and type names (date,name), even those from other platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL employs a concept known as **domain name integrity** which means that the names of objects have a scope given by their container.

Column names have to be unique, but only within the context of the table that contains the columns.  Table names have to be unique, but only within the context of the schema that contains the tables, etc.

When you query columns you need to reference the schema, table and colum that you are interested in, unless one or more of these can be inferred.  Unless your query is so simple that it only references one table, you're going to need to reference the table name directly or by using an alias, e.g. Customer.ID or C.ID from Customer C, etc.

The first option is a throw-back to technical requirements for uniqueness of all column names, which applied to old ISAM databases and to languages like COBOL in the 1960s and 70s.  This got dragged along for no good reason into dBase in the 1980s and has stuck as a convention well into the relational and object DBMS eras.  **Resist this outdated convention.**

The second approach is much simpler and more readable.  Simpler and more readable code is easier to write and much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Keys are "propagated" down foreign keys, so it's useful if they keep their names constant in all the resulting "copies". It just makes the database schema clearer: you don't have to look into FK definition<sup>1</sup> to see where a particular field came from - you can do that by just glancing at its name.

On the other hand, non-key fields are not propagated and there is no particular reason to keep their names unique outside their respective tables.

So, I'd recommend a hybrid approach:

- Prefix key field names to keep them unique among all tables and avoid any need for renaming propagated fields.
- Don't prefix non-key field names to keep them shorter, even though this might lead to some name repetition in different tables.

For example:

```
Customer (CustomerID, Name, Addres, Gender)
Staff (StaffID, Name, Address, Gender)
```

And if you happen to have a junction table between the two<sup>2</sup>, it'll look like this...

```
CustomerStaff(CustomerID PK FK1, StaffID PK FK2)
```

...so no need for renames (that would be necessary if both parent keys were named `ID`) and it's immediately clear where `CustomerID` and `StaffID` came from. Also, I personally don't like shortening table names in the prefix (hence `CustomerID` and not `CusID`), as this makes naming even more "mechanical" and predictable.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Potentially multiple levels of them!*

*<sup>2</sup> Just an example. Whether it makes sense is another matter.*

Comment: There is no particular reason, other than personal preference, to have a naming convention that says the name of a foreign key field should be equal to the name of a primary key field.  In fact, it often happens that one table might have multiple foreign keys to the same parent, so it is sometimes necessary for there to be a difference between the foreign key name and the primary key name.  Some people believe fervently that prefixing primary key names with a table indication _harms_ readability, not the other way around.

Comment: @JoelBrown As I explained in my answer, there is a reason beyond just personal preference: ability to immediately know where a particular migrated key came from, by just reading its name. As for multiple FKs to the same parent, this certainly doesn't happen often (one common case I can think of is implementing a DAG), and even if it did there are consistent renaming schemes that preserve the "spirit" of the name so it's still clear where it came from. As for people that _"believe fervently that prefixing ... harms readability"_, I'd like them to explain _why_?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic BTW, NATURAL JOIN and JOIN ... USING can benefit from identical names.

Comment: As I explained in my comment, I'm not talking about prefixing foreign keys.  I'm talking about prefixing primary keys.  Customer.ID and Order.CustomerID are perfectly readable and you know exactly just where the foreign key came from.  Customer.CustomerID adds no information and using a convention that expects most primary key and foreign key names to align invites lazy or inexperienced programmers to rely on natural joins which often leads to confusion.

Comment: @JoelBrown Yes, but that requires people to consistently follow a specific "renaming" convention, in opposition to what a typical modeling tool will do by default. For me, its simpler to just have a naming convention for PK and let the tool transfer that name to migrated keys. Also, visually "parsing" the model doesn't really involve reading all these names - it's more like matching the visual shapes. That being said, I have to admin that both of these things are somewhat personal - consistent renaming is not that difficult to do and people might differ in their "visuality".

Answer (score 2):

ID is a SQL antipattern (http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1343835938&sr=1-1&keywords=sql+antipatterns), never name a column ID.
I would use:

```
Customer(CustomerID, Name, Address, Gender) 
Staff(StaffID, Name, Address, Gender)
```

Comment: Whether or not "ID" is a SQL anti-pattern is a matter of religious war.  People who are enamoured with natural joins consider ID to be an anti-pattern.  On the other hand, there are other people who consider natural joins to be lazy and sloppy and an anti-pattern in and of themselves.

Comment: I don't use natural joins (SQL Server doesn't allow them and I would not anyway as I agree it is poor technique) Nonetheless, it is inherent on you to protect your database by not using a technique guaranteed to cause problems if some later person down the road does use natural joins. That's basic design, never create something that is too easy t obe misused. I also know it is an antipattern because I write complex reporting queries where it also creates a problem.

Comment: I also note, I have  a reference written by one of the top SQl experts also calling it an antipattern.

Comment: Merely being Bill Karwin does not exempt one from taking sides in a holy war.  Also, you should actually read what Karwin says.  He doesn't like "ID" because it isn't descriptive and because some languages can't use the natural join syntactic shortcut of assuming two columns with the same name will join.  (SQL "JOIN ON" etc).  There are lots of people who would shun natural joins and SQL JOIN ON syntax and also lots of people who would argue that Karwin's rational for avoiding column name confusion doesn't hold water, since every column in a query should have an alias as a matter of good form.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the second option is better. If you decide to change the table name, you won't have to change the names of all the columns. Also when you write your SELECT statements, you usually use an alias anyway ("select sta.name, sta.adress from staff sta...")
In general, when in doubt, always pick a simpler solution.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Every Industry has its own standard. In those both style of designing's are normal.  It is recommended to use First one.

```
Customer(CusID, CusName, CusAddres, CusGender)
Staff(StaID, StaName, StaAddress, StaGender)
```

Because it is using table name symbol like `Customer` to `Cus` and `Staff` to `Sta`. It helps 
the project good to maintenance.

Some Organizations are also using `vch` for `VARCHAR` data type,`int` for `INT` data type.

Like

```
Customer(intCusID, vchCusName, vchCusAddres, vchCusGender)
Staff(intStaID, vchStaName, vchStaAddress, vchStaGender)
```

Comment: I personally do not like this. I see absolutely no need to repeat the entity name on each field. In queries you will normally use the tablename in front of the fieldname. Unless when you have only one table, but then it would not make sense to repeat either.

Comment: Thnx mate. You may be right. But, we are using such like field name and most our database has more than 100 no. of tables.